# $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, general-topology, real-numbers

Prove that$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx =   \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx $$ Given that $f(x)$ is continuous in $(a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon) $ but is infinite at $a$ and $b$.

**Attempt:**
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=  \int_{a}^{a+\epsilon} f(x) dx  +  \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx+  \int_{b-\epsilon}^{b} f(x) dx  $$
Now,$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{a+\epsilon} f(x) dx=0$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{b-\epsilon}^{b} f(x) dx=0$$
So, $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx =   \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx $$

Comment: If you know the statements about the limits on small subintervals then yes this works. Do you know how to prove those "from scratch"?

Comment: @Ian No I don't know. Please answer Ian.

Comment: Well, then what you need depends on the level of rigor expected of you by the person asking the question, which is going to be different in say calc II vs. real analysis.

Comment: Also in this case with singularities on both ends, there are some ways that this could go awry, like the integral not actually converging but the symmetric limit does converge anyway...

Comment: @Ian I prefer real analysis approach. Please answer. Actually f is discontinuous at a and b but continuous elsewhere

Comment: Yeah, with the pair of singularities being there, this problem isn't totally well specified; for example, can I assume the improper Riemann integral strictly speaking exists? If so, then you can send the limits outward however you want and get the same result so in particular you can do it symmetrically. But in general just because you get a value when you do the limit symmetrically does not mean you will get the same value when you do the limit asymmetrically; see the concept of "Cauchy principal value".

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Please write as an answer.

Comment: @Ian My f is integrable in [a,b]

Comment: If it's assumed improperly Riemann integrable or properly Lebesgue integrable then it's automatic from the definition of that concept, no need for an answer really.

Comment: @Ian No it is not Riemann Integrable. It is discontinuous at a and b. Please answer

Comment: @Ian f is discontinuous at a and b, so can it be improperly Riemann integrable?

Comment: If it is improperly Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ (which can happen even if it blows up at $a$ and/or $b$) then the property that you want is automatic from the definition of the improper Riemann integral.

Comment: @Ian What I need to show in order to prove that f is improperly Riemann integrable?

Comment: That depends what you're given, which is why I was saying that this isn't totally specified. Basically, either the symbol $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ you're using is just not well-defined, or else this property necessarily holds.

Comment: @Ian I just want to know that how to show a particular function improperly integrable?

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot. Please answer my last question.

Comment: It amounts to showing $\lim_{(\delta,\epsilon) \to (0^+,0^+)} \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\delta} f(x) dx$ exists (which means it is independent of the path taken to approach $(0,0)$ from the first quadrant).

Comment: @Ian Should $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ be necessarily distinct?

Comment: Not *necessarily*, but the path where they're the same is just one path. The other paths need to give the same outcome for the improper Riemann integral to technically exist.

Comment: Another, perhaps easier way to think about it is that it suffices to have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{a+\epsilon}^c f(x) dx$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_c^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx$ both existing, where $a<c<b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c\in(a,b)$. We have
$$ \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx = \int_{a+\epsilon}^{c} f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx $$
By the definition of an improper integral, we have
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^{c} f(x) dx =: \int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx $$
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{c}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx =: \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx $$
assuming these limits exist. We have then
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx  $$
Note that it is possible that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx$ exists even if $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^{c} f(x) dx$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{c}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx $ don't exist separately. This happens for example for $a=-1$, $b=1$, $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$.